# tapestry zone update with post field in request

Tags: ajax, prototypejs, tapestry

is there way to update tapestry zone by `ZoneManager` with `POST` field in request to server?

this works fine...

```
var zoneManager = Tapestry.findZoneManager($('textarea'));
var listenerURIWithValue = this.listenerURI;
listenerURIWithValue = this.addRequestParameter('param', $('textarea').value,     listenerURIWithValue);
zoneManager.updateFromURL(listenerURIWithValue);
```

but what if I have too long string in textarea? I need to send the `$('textarea').value` as a `POST`, not `GET`.

Has anybody an idea? Thank you for your responds.

Comment: why all the custom javascript and not a form submit to your zone and have Tapestry do all the js for you?

Comment: what is `this` and how can `textarea` be a zone element and an input field?

Comment: This code is part of tapestry mixin for textarea or input. [link](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/ajax/onevent) But that is not the point. My problem was the GET method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I listed in Tapestry-prototypejs source code and finally I found the solution. Function updateFromUrl has another parameter.

```
zoneManager.updateFromURL(listenerURIWithValue, 
        {
            "method": "post",
            "parameter": $('textarea').value
        });
```